# O365 Attachment API got "Unable to cast object of type" error

Tags: office365-apps, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

Any resolution/mitigation on this?
The issue can be reproduced on API explorer (https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net) with following REST API Repro steps:

Logon API Explorer with your tenant, https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net

Get the group conversation attachments with following API In my case:

You will get following error:
Request duration: 6086 ms. CollapseExpandRawJSON Error: 500 - Internal Server Error See Response Headers for details. { "error": { "code": "ErrorInternalServerError", "message": "**Unable to cast object of type** 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.AttachmentSchema' to type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Web.IRequestBuilderForEntitySet`2[Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Post,Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Attachment]'.", "innerError": { "request-id": "89efeca6-ba17-478b-aa8e-f3bf6ec32cd0", "date": "2016-01-08T09:56:39" } } }
Thanks,
Raymond

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the service. The fix for it is being rolled out and you should no longer see the error.